# "[]" is an invalid JSON primitive?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

I get the error `Invalid JSON primitive`. So I keep simplifying my JSON string, right down to the empty array: `[]` I even checked that the string looks right, and has length 2.

I do believe that `[]` should be valid for an array of anything?

My code is

```
jsonString = "[]";
var v = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Felagi[] felagar = (Felagi[])v.Deserialize<Felagi[]>("jsonString");
```

and for what it may be worth, the class I try to deserialize is

```
public class Felagi
{
    public String firstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "[ ]" is a list/array of something

Comment: You aren't attempting to deserialize an array.  "jsonString" is not valid JSON.

Comment: You're passing the string `"jsonString"`, not the variable named `jsonString`.

Remove the quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize the string literal `"jsonstring"`, not the contents of variable `jsonString`.
Try

```
Felagi[] felagar = (Felagi[])v.Deserialize<Felagi[]>(jsonString);
```